# Play! 2 Rendering JSON data in View from Controller

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10

based on this http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2012/10/14/play-framework-2-0-rendering-json-data-in-the-view/

myview:

```
    @(message: String)(myobjects:ObjectNode)
@import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
@import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode
```

controller:

```
ObjectNode myobjects = objectsDAO.getObjects();
return ok(myview.render("test",myobjects ));
```

error

```
 not found: type ObjectNode
```

Doesn't seem to work with ObjectNode, the imports in the view don't seem to be working. Could not find much documentation about passing the view a JSON

Comment: What version of Play are you using? That post you are referring to is relatively old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining it as such: `@(message: String, myobjects:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode)`, or if that doesn't work, put the `@imports` in your `main.scala.html` since it holds the content of your other views....

```
<body>
    @content
</body>
```

Comment: If I recall right it has something to do with which classes Play Framework imports by default. For example, everything in your .models package is imported by default, so if you have say a models.Product class, you don't need full path to Product in the view. However Jackson classes are not in your models folder... but in a separate jar somewhere on the build path. I'll try to lookup some notes I made for myself a little later to see if I can expand on this, but if I recall right - thats the crux of the issue.

Comment: I was thinking more of why the @import didn't work and it had to be put inside the brackets

Comment: Its kind of the same issue really, in your view you've attempted to use an object type before declaring its import. Did you try to do it the second way - put all of your imports into the main.scala.html so that they are initialized before your object type parameters are processed? Try that and see what happens....